# Negative top margin not working in IE 8 or 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a div with `margin-top:-200px`. I want the div to move up/behind the div above it.

Works great in all browsers except IE so far. `margin-top:200px` works, so I know it's not a collapsing margin issue.

Is there a bug I am not aware of here?

Comment: what about using position absolute and z-index?

Comment: Could you show some code? Preferably, a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) test case.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

IE doesn't like negative margins and doesn't render them properly. Position your elements relatively or absolutely and use `top: -200px` instead.

***Note:** positioning them may change the layout significantly and you may have to rework your styles.*

Comment: it's hard to judge without having seen his particular case.

Comment: Yes but I have had many issues in the past with IE not reading negative margins correctly. It's a good practice to try and not use them to position elements.

Comment: fair enough...I had already implemented relative positioning, which forces me to use a negative margin on the bottom to pull up the content below. I was just hoping to get some understanding on why negative margin doesn't work on the top. I guess that's just too much to ask from IE :)

Sorry I couldn't provide more code, but it's relatively complex and I was hoping to just discover a common problem/solution floating around out there.

Comment: @SideDishStudio: The problem with your question was that "negative margins on the top" *do work* in IE8/9 (see: http://jsfiddle.net/ERZhS/). So there wasn't really enough information to give a good answer.

Comment: Had same problem with trying to position a div over an image. Tried for a solution for well over an hour and finally found this post. Changed to position: relative in an IE-conditional and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Relative positioning and negative left worked great for my issue.

Answer (score 14):

Negative margin hide the div…
Here is trick
use zoom:1, position: relative

**Problem:**

```
.container{
padding: 20px;
}
.toolbar{
margin-top: -10px ;
}
```

in IE red area of toolbar div hide itself. even we are using zoom: 1. to get rid of this problem we need to add position: relative too.

**Solution:**

so your css class will become

```
.container{
padding: 20px;
}
.toolbar{
margin-top: -10px ;
zoom: 1;
position: relative;
}
```

http://trickyclicks.com

Comment: For me to work I added 
`display: inline-block;`
to the inner element (.toolbar in this case)

Answer (score 3):

If the above doesn't help: make sure there's a div around your offending div. Now add a width of 100% to the offending div and float it to the left. Like this. Got rid of all my negative margin ie woes...

```
div.container {}
div.offender /*inside div.container*/ {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: -20px;   /* ie fix */
  zoom: 1;                /* ie fix */
  position: relative;     /* ie fix */
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

give position as relative. inline style is advisable. It may give some problem if you use external css.

Answer (score 1):

In order to support negative margins in IE, I've fixed similar issues with `display: table;`.  Other fixes like `zoom: 1;` and `position: relative;` don't always work (at least in my experience).  If you only want to add this style to IE, I'd suggest using https://modernizr.com/

```
// using comment to show that .no-cssreflections belongs to the html tag
/*html*/.no-cssreflections .container { display: table; }
```

Comment: `display: table;` around a parent `<div>` did the trick for me