# Negative margin-top in IE is ignored

Tags: css, internet-explorer, margin

I have a  transparent header which is positioned over a window height slider. I have used a negative margin-top equal to the header height which works everywhere except IE.

I have tested in IE 10 and 9 and they all fail to apply the negative margin on top unless I apply overflow hidden to the header. I cannot apply overflow hidden to the header as it has dropdown navigation.

Do negative margins work under divs that do not have overflow hidden or have a set height in IE?

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Can you make a http://codepen.io/ ? just press pen as soon you are in there, and add your source code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Negative top margin not working in IE 8 or 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506844/negative-top-margin-not-working-in-ie-8-or-9)

Answer (score -1):

IE doesn't like negative margins and doesn't render them properly. Position your elements relatively or absolutely and use top: -200px instead.

Note: positioning them may change the layout significantly and you may have to rework your styles.

--
Already been answered here
[Negative top margin not working in IE 8 or 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506844/negative-top-margin-not-working-in-ie-8-or-9)

Comment: Sorry I cannot produce the code as I have altered everything at this stage and it is a wordpress template.The thing is that if I try this out under a div that has overflow: hidden the negative margin works in all IE versions. So i am just trying to find out if overflow:hidden is always required on the element above the one with the negative margin for this to work in IE?